# How do I search and jump to a tab on Notepad++ using the name of the file?

Tags: notepad++

I would like to know how to **search and jump to a tab open in Notepad++ based on the name of the file.**

I often open 50+ scripts/functions on Notepad++ and use things like RegEx to find and replace all those 50+ scripts. Sometimes I need to debug one specific script that would affect all the others, so it would be nice to search for the specific text file based on the name.

I have considered the shortcut mapper hotkeys like the *1st-9th tab hotkeys with Ctrl+Numpad #, "Next Tab" = "Ctrl+Page down", "Previous Tab" = "Ctrl+Page up"*, and so forth, but that those aren't very efficient with enormous amount of tabs.

Another option I've considered is closing all of them, opening the one I want to look at from Windows Explorer, editing and doing whatever, and then opening all of them again, but that's rather tedious. I suppose if I had multi-instance "-multiInst" mode enabled, I wouldn't have to close everything, albeit still inconvenient.

My ideal solution is some drop-down menu given I have maybe 30 or less scripts, and also a way to search for my tabs for over 30 like typing in a search bar.

I've done my Google searches, but I have not found anything about this. I hope I'm not missing something obvious, but I'm hoping someone may have an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just realized after posting that the **"Window"** tab exists, and it basically is the drop-down menu option I've mentioned to view all your open windows and select which one:

[image]

This should work for tabs under maybe 30 depending on your monitor screen, and I figure with too many tabs, it won't display the additional ones.

I'm still looking for a war to search for the name of a tab when there are are enormous amount of tabs that exceed the display limit of the "Window" tab.

Answer (score 2):

There is also smthg under:

- right mouse click in empty space on icon bar (on top)
- while holding right mouse button pressed - move your mouse wheel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned large number of open files is somewhat unusual for me. But well, each user has special requirements.

From my point of view, the Notepad++ GUI already offers a very extensive functionality here. Even with more than 30 open tabs (49 files in the example) a selection is possible. A scroll bar appears in the window on the right.

I therefore suggest to use the existing functionality.

[image]